# AppleScript works in Editor but not in Outlook

Tags: outlook, applescript, osx-mavericks, outlook-2011

This works in the AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to activate
tell application "System Events"
  click menu item "Block Sender" of menu "Junk Mail" of menu item "Junk Mail" of menu "Message" of menu bar item "Message" in menu bar 1 of process "Outlook"
end tell
```

However, when I move this script to Outlook's script folder (`~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Outlook Script Menu Items/`) and attempt to run it from Outlook's script menu, I get an error:

> System Events got an error: Can't get menu bar 1 of process "Outlook".
>   Invalid index.

Should I not be using `System Events`?

Comment: Is the process really named "Outlook"? In your other question you wrote `application process "Microsoft Outlook"`.

Comment: I've used "Outlook" and "Microsoft Outlook".  Both have the same effects in both contexts.

Comment: It's actually the wrong error, but has Outlook access to control your computer?

Comment: No, it isn't listed in the 'Privacy' section of the Accessibility section of the Security & Privacy System Preference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to. Drag Outlook to the list.

Comment: Added it to the list; restarted Outlook for good measure.  No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in Outlook now that Outlook plugin scripts can't access the menu bar in UI scripting, even if Outlook is added to the Security list of apps that can control your computer.
You have two workaround options.

1. Save your script in system-wide script menu at /Library/Scripts/ in which case you'll first be prompted with "osascript is not allowed assistive access". You need to go to System Preferences/Security & Privacy/Privacy/Accessibility and enable SystemUIServer
   Then, that script will run from that system-wide menu instead of Outlook's script menu.
2. You could set a keyboard combo to the "Block Sender" menu item using System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts. You could then just use that key combo yourself, or if you still need to do through a script, the script can call that key combo using UI scripting.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: How do you assign a shortcut to a script?  System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts/App Shortcuts?  Can the script be in any folder?

Comment: You can not assign a shortcut to a script in Apple's keyboard shortcuts. You can only assign those to app menu items. See the screenshots I attached to my answer.   And, as for "can the script be in any folder", are you asking about the system-wide script menu? Scripts are place in ~/Library/Scripts/ like I said.

Comment: I was able to assign a keyboard shortcut to a macro in Outlook's scripts menu.